# Install mysql-server and set password from the command line?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-10.04, password

I am installing MySQL via the command line: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`.  During the installation process, it prompts me for a root password.

How can I specify the MySQL password without having to wait for the screen to pop up and ask me the password? Is there a parameter I can pass to `apt-get` to specify the MySQL root password so that I can write a script to perform the installation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it for you

> echo mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password password PASSWORD | debconf-set-selections
>
> echo mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password_again password PASSWORD | debconf-set-selections
>
> apt-get install -y mysql-server

Obviously you would replace PASSWORD with whatever you would want your MySQL root password to be

Comment: Probably want to add `-y` to the install line for a scripted installation.

Comment: Good catch Shane. I've edited my answer to reflect the change.

Comment: perfect, thank you! I was not aware of the debconf-set-selections script.